# IP and DNS Connection problems in Zesty

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, ip, dnsmasq

first of all, NetworkManager sets my DNS to 127.0.0.53. No DNS service is running by default. I installed dnsmasq, but it still fails to look names up. I added some dns servers to the resolv.conf.d/head
This lets me look stuff up with nslookup
when i try to ping by name, it cant find it despite it working in nslookup. ping google.com does eventually work, but it takes a good 10-15 seconds to resolve.

```
gretchen@CyanTechnology:~$ nslookup s3.amazonaws.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
s3.amazonaws.com    canonical name = s3-1.amazonaws.com.
Name:   s3-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 52.216.163.37

gretchen@CyanTechnology:~$ ping 52.216.163.37
PING 52.216.163.37 (52.216.163.37) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 52.216.163.37: icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=76.7 ms
64 bytes from 52.216.163.37: icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=70.2 ms
64 bytes from 52.216.163.37: icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=74.0 ms
^C
--- 52.216.163.37 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 70.283/73.703/76.754/2.673 ms
gretchen@CyanTechnology:~$ ping s3.amazonaws.com
ping: s3.amazonaws.com: Name or service not known
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo resolvconf -u` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I found a solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/81797/nslookup-finds-ip-but-ping-doesnt